Add a caption to an image using the command line
I want to add a caption to an existing image (saving as a new image) and it seems imagemagick seems to do what that but none of the examples I've seen explain how to do it in the way I want, which is to append it as a new part of the image at the bottom leaving the entire existing image visible. The caption should be black text on white, and the white background should fill the entire width of the image, regardless of what that width is.
Ideally, the caption should be determined from a subset of the file name - e.g. a file name ending "a.jpg" should be labelled "Location A", one ending "cclue.jpg" as "Location C clue", "key.png" as "key to images", etc. I think ideally I'd like these to be defined in a text file I can keep updated. This second paragraph isn't essential though.

not familiar enough with ImageMagick, but I'd guess: 1. Enlarge Canvas, 2. Use the examples. Note that askubuntu is not a script writing service.

OK thank you, Can you recommend somewhere that does offer script writing?


google? "How to enlarge canvas using imagemagick"? 2. the examples you found earlier? 3. Include your findings above (which may trigger answers, to help you out), or even as an answer if you find something that works for you? www.tldp.org -> Bash guides may provide basic help if Bash scripting is beyond your knowledge.

